# Problem in python 3: "IndexError: list index out of range" when creating 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, 2d

```
    grid = []
for i in range(3):
    grid[i] = []
    for j in range(3):
        grid[i][j] = 0

print(grid)
```

So this is my code - i am trying to create a 2D list and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/pc/Desktop/pyton/app/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    grid[i].append([])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I searched and searched but couldn't find a solution. Please help

Comment: You create grid as an empty list (meaning it doesn't have any element or index available). When you do `grid[i]` it will give an index out of range error.

Comment: `grid` is an empty list, so `grid[0]` does not exist.  (Also, the error message clearly refers to a line of code that does not exist in your post.  It really helps if you post the real code you're actually using.)

Comment: You can `append` new items to an empty list but not to non-existent items in the list.

Comment: `grid = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured it out. The code is missing one line in the start (an import line) and im a begginer. I just used this method in javascript so i figured it would work in python.